# VBA script not affecting first cell in a table

Tags: vba, ms-word, trim

I have a VBA script designed to strip non-breaking spaces out of a table in Microsoft Word by searching for NBSPS and then replacing them with regular spaces and then using trim to clean up spaces before and after text. As it stand, the code will work for everything except trimming the first cell in a table (it does however, replace the spaces in the first cell). I was hoping to find out if there are any unique behaviors to Word/VBA that might cause this as I will be making several macros for tables in MS Word.

```
Sub nbsbCleanupQuick()
' use find and replace to replace all nbsp in the table with regular spaces
' use trim to clean up unwanted spaces
' For some reason this macro will replace nbsp with regular spaces but will not trim in the first cell of a table

' vars for counting
Dim numRows, numCells As Integer
Dim rindex, cindex As Integer

'container for cell contents
Dim container As String

Selection.Tables(1).Select
numRows = Selection.Rows.Count

For rindex = 1 To numRows
numCells = Selection.Tables(1).Rows(rindex).Cells.Count
For cindex = 1 To numCells
    container = ""
    Selection.Tables(1).Rows(rindex).Cells(cindex).Range.Select
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = Chr(160)
        .Replacement.Text = Chr(32)
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
    End With
    If (Len(Selection.Text) - 2 > 0) Then
        container = Left(Selection.Text, Len(Selection.Text) - 2)
    End If
    Selection.Text = Trim(container)
Next
Next

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: what text you have in your first cell? type it here exactly as it is. The thing is that your code is working fine for me...

Comment: Different texts, in fact the first cell is often empty with only 1 nbsp and the macro replaces the nbsp with a regular space but does not remove the empty space from the first cell. Honestly, for what I need that is perfectly fine... for now. I'd just like to know what could cause it to only perform half of the operations on that first cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are at the beginning of bigger project I'll give you some advices with some more changes of your code. See proposed solution below with some comments explaining reasons for changes inside the code. Obviously this solves the problem you described in your question.

```
Sub nbsbCleanupQuick()
' use find and replace to replace all nbsp in the table with regular spaces
' use trim to clean up unwanted spaces
' For some reason this macro will replace nbsp with regular spaces but will not trim in the first cell of a table

' vars for counting
Dim numRows, numCells As Integer
Dim rindex, cindex As Integer

'container for cell contents
Dim container As String

Selection.Tables(1).Select
numRows = Selection.Rows.Count

'do replacement once, at the beginning
'it will be more efficient option
    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Select
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = Chr(160)
        .Replacement.Text = Chr(32)
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll ', Wrap:=wdFindContinue
        'keep wrap parameter switch off to do replacement only within table 1
    End With

'to iterate through all cells in table use this kind of loop
Dim tblCell As Cell
For Each tblCell In ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.Cells

        'it's not necessary to select but I didn't want to
        'change your solution completly
        tblCell.Select

    'this check is easier to understand
    If (Len(Selection.Text) > 2) Then
        container = Left(Selection.Text, Len(Selection.Text) - 2)
    End If
    Selection.Text = Trim(container)

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This is interesting in deed. I didn't realize that the with block would execute on the entire table without the wrap::continue. The "activedocument.tables(1)" line to me implies it grabs the first table in the document. My documents have upwards of 30 tables which is why I had it set up to force the user to select a table rather than reference a specific table. If the warp::continue line affects all tables in a document that explains why the macro could take several minutes to work sometimes. This gives me much to consider. Thank you.